# Why is energy lost here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Let's say a $1 \ \text{kg}$ block is moving.
With a speed of $1 \ \text{m/s}$ so its kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2} \ \text{J}$. Now let's gently place a block of mass $3 \ \text{kg}$. Now as linear momentum is conserved due to lack of external forces on the system the blocks move together with velocity $1/4 \ \text{m/s}$ but the energy is now $\frac{1}{8} \ \text{J}$ which is lesser than it used to be.

Where has the energy gone?

Comment: Energy can be in forms other than kinetic energy of the block

Comment: Place a block – where? and how?

Answer (score 2):

Energy is lost due to work done by friction . Try to analyze each block individually.

Comment: You can add in the fact that mechanical energy is not conserved in cases where non-conservative internal forces are present to generalize your answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be due to friction necessarily. Really any force will do.

Answer (score 0):

"let's gently place a block of mass 3 kg"

Maybe you should rethink the system. You cannot "add stuff" just like this. Energy is conserved in an isolated system. Adding a block just like this is not what I would consider as isolated at all.

Put the two blocks (or one) and then tell us what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let the initial body be $A$ and let it move along $X$ axis. Let the other one be $B$

The reason why we get loss of energy is because we are looking at half the picture. Ideally if body $B$ was to fall on to body $A$, then it should bounce back from conservation of momentum (no matter how small the speed of placement was). But some stickiness to the surface is preventing this. **So the energy of motion of block $B$ was absorbed by this attractive sticking force.** The full story of what happens to the energy and why we generally call this loss a heat loss is there below.

As some answers mention, we cannot add stuff to the system. So a different form of this question is more reasonable.
Imagine a body $A$ moving along $X$ axis over a table (no gravity no friction). Let another mass $B$ be slowly approaching $A$, collides with $A$ and *sticks* to $A$. This is equivalent to placing the body gently.

**where the energy goes**

If no stickiness existed, Body $B$ bounces off from $A$ trying to move away but the sticky force pulls it back with all molecules in glue pulling back.

Now a when the molecules of the body and glue attract each other, both molecules would gain speed. the mutual attraction transfers the energy slowly from $B$ into the glue molecules.

This higher speeds would increase the vibration of atoms in the glue, which is equivalent to a rise in temperature. That is why we also call this **heat loss**

**the main take away is that - as feynman says - there is no non-conservative forces. Energy is always conserved but we are lazy to calculate all the energy.**

Also to mention this is generally known as a perfectly inelastic collision.